# String permutations with recursion?

Tags: java, string, recursion, permutation

So the problem I'm trying to solve is creating a program that creates the permutations of a string using recursion, with these two helper methods:

```
    public static void displayPermutation(String s)
    public static void displayPermutation(String s1, String s2)
```

The first method simply invokes a helper method, which is then supposed to use a loop that continuously moves a character from s2, which is the initial string, to s1, which is initially empty.

Below, I have tried the following way of recursively moving characters one by one from s2 to s1, but I keep getting an error for whatever reason:

```
    public static void displayPermutation(String s) {
    //Invoke second displayPermutation method
    displayPermutation("", s);
}

public static void displayPermutation(String s1, String s2) {
    //Stopping condition
    if (s2 == "")
        System.out.println(s1);

    else {
        displayPermutation(s1 + s2.substring(0, 1), s2.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: What's the error message and what is the output supposed to look like? Do you really mean permutations or something else?

Comment: It's not the braces, it would be too clear in that respect haha.  More like StackOverflow and indexOutOfRange errors

Comment: Yes permutations - for example if I enter abc, it should return the following: abc, abc, bac, bca, cab, cba

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare strings with `==`, use `.equals()` instead. Also you need a loop that goes through all available characters in s2.

```
public class Permutations {
    public static void displayPermutation(String s) {
        //Invoke second displayPermutation method
        displayPermutation("", s);
    }

    public static void displayPermutation(String s1, String s2) {
        //Stopping condition
        if (s2.equals("")) {
            System.out.println(s1);
        } else {
            for(int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
                displayPermutation(s1 + s2.substring(i, i+1), s2.substring(0, i) + s2.substring(i+1));
            }
        }
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        displayPermutation("abc");
     }
}
```

Comment: in recursion it is prohibited to use loop

Comment: Not true. Only if it's homework and loops are explicitly forbidden by the teacher.

Answer (score 1):

To get Permutation recursively (if you need the mirror of the word :: permuation of letters of the string) you need to use

> s2.substring(s2.length-1, s2.length);

that way you will take the last character in first.

then you have to use

> s2.substring(0, s2.length-1);

verbally we take the last character from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

For better programs and answers i have found http://javainhouse.blogspot.in/2016/01/program-in-java-to-print-fibonacci.html program which is using the recursion method perfectly